# I need to Merge Two mysql columns to one jtable column

Tags: java

I need to Merge Two mysql columns to one jtable column. Here is the code I used to do that.

```
        ResultSet search = Main.DB.search("select * from users");
        DefaultTableModel dtm= (DefaultTableModel)users.getModel();
        while (search.next()) {

            Vector v = new Vector();
            v.add(search.getString(1));
            v.add(search.getString(2));
            v.add(search.getString(5+""+6)); // need to merge column 6 and 6
            v.add(search.getString(7));

            dtm.addRow(v);
```

Please Help me to do that.

Thank you

Comment: It's tough to determine from this alone what you're having problems with.  We don't have access to your database, nor do we have an acute insight into your specific requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> v.add(search.getString(5+""+6));

Why would you think you can "merge" the parameters of the getString(...) method?

You need to get each value separately:

```
String column5 = search.getString(5);
String column6 = search.getString(6);
v.add(column5 + " : " + column6);
```